# How to convert a protected property in VB.net to c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a property in vb.net and i want to convert it to c# code.

```
Protected ReadOnly Property SummariesAdapter() As ArticleSummariesTableAdapter
    Get
        If _ArticleSummariesAdapter Is Nothing Then
            _ArticleSummariesAdapter = New ArticleSummariesTableAdapter()
        End If

        Return _ArticleSummariesAdapter
    End Get
End Property
```

Any help?

Comment: http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected ArticleSummariesTableAdapter SummariesAdapter {
    get {
        if (_ArticleSummariesAdapter == null) {
            _ArticleSummariesAdapter = new ArticleSummariesTableAdapter();
        }

        return _ArticleSummariesAdapter;
    }
}
```

This code conversion by [telerik](http://converter.telerik.com/).  (probably all the others are too :)

Answer (score 1):

```
protected readonly ArticleSummariesTableAdapter SummariesAdapter
{
  get
  {
     if (_ArticleSummariesAdapter == null)
     {
       _ArticleSummariesAdapter = New ArticleSummariesTableAdapter();
     }

     return _ArticleSummariesAdapter;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is your c# code

```
protected ArticleSummariesTableAdapter SummariesAdapter {
    get {
        if (_ArticleSummariesAdapter == null) {
            _ArticleSummariesAdapter = new ArticleSummariesTableAdapter();
        }

        return _ArticleSummariesAdapter;
    }
}
```

I used [**http://converter.telerik.com/**](http://converter.telerik.com/) to covert vb to c#

You can also use
[**http://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/**](http://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/)

OR

[**http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/SnippetConverter.aspx**](http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/SnippetConverter.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
protected ArticleSummariesTableAdapter SummariesAdapter {
    get {
        if (_ArticleSummariesAdapter == null) {
            _ArticleSummariesAdapter = new ArticleSummariesTableAdapter();
        }

        return _ArticleSummariesAdapter;
    }
}
```

Use these links to conert C# to Vb or Vb to C#

http://converter.telerik.com/

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp